# Batch alert if folder content not updated within time period

Tags: file, batch-file, updates

A folder gets updated with new file content every minute.

A simple alert (eg start echo) needs to be raised if it has been detected that the monitored folder's contents have not been updated in the last five minutes.

eg,

Monitor c:\monitoredFiles
If (c:\monitoredFiles has not been updated in 5 minutes) {start echo 'System Malfunction Detected'}

Answer (score 0):

Here is something quick and dirty I have put together. It basically creates a directory listing of folder G: (because that is what I have, you can change it) and saves it in C: (you can save it somewhere else). Then every 10 seconds it generates a new directory listing and compares it with the old one, using `FC` (file compare). If they haven't changed, it outputs a message. You can output a different message using a different technique.

```
@echo off
REM Start monitoring G:\
REM Goto our "working area"
C:
CD \
REM Generate initial listing
dir G:\ | FINDSTR /v (s) > old.tmp
:TOP
dir G:\ | FINDSTR /v (s) > new.tmp
fc new.tmp old.tmp > nul
if errorlevel 1 goto ok
echo No changes detected
:ok
del old.tmp 2> nul
ren new.tmp old.tmp
SLEEP 10
GOTO TOP
```

The `FINDSTR` parts suppress the two lines at the bottom of a DIR listing so that changes elsewhere in the filesystem that change the free space do not affect this program. It searches for, and removes (/V) lines containing (s), i.e. those two lines with 50 File(s) and 5 Dir(s) at the end.

```
05/03/2014  10:23               845 z
14/02/2014  10:16                94 z.html
              50 File(s)     75,284,594 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  202,621,149,184 bytes free
```

Note that I change directory to C:\ at the start because I don't want to write in the directory I am monitoring, else I will cause it to change myself. Obviously you can write your version to generate its files anywhere you like - I just kind of like C:\ because it is pretty likely to exist.

Comment: Thank you Mark, I look forward to try this :)

Comment: Did this work out for you? If so, please accept my answer so I get a lovely big green tick. If not, please say what went wrong so that I, or someone cleverer than me, can assist you further. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This script gets the most recent file and checks if it is over 5 minutes old.
It will simply echo a message to the screen atm.

You can launch it using another script in a loop like this - it runs every minute:

```
@echo off
:loop
call "checkfolder.bat"
timeout /t 60 /nobreak
goto :loop
```

Here is "checkfolder.bat"

```
@echo off
:: Wmic removes regional differences
:: XP Pro can have some filename errors due to the short filename bug

setlocal
:: set the number of minutes in the following line
set minutes=5

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "stamp=%YYYY% %MM% %DD% %HH% %Min%"
call :DateToMinutes %stamp% NowMins

set "name="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir * /a-d /b /od ^|find /v /i "%~nx0"') do set "name=%%a"
if defined name call :CheckMins "%name%"
if %MinsOld% gtr %minutes% echo Folder hasn't been modified in %minutes% minutes & pause

goto :EOF

:CheckMins
set "filestamp="
set "filemins="
set "MinsOld="
set "YY=" & set "YYYY=" & set "MM=" & set "DD="
set "HH=" & set "Min=" & set "Sec=" & set "dt="
set "file=%~sf1"
:: can use CreationDate instead of lastmodified
WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name="%file:\=\\%" get lastmodified | find "." >file.tmp
for /f %%a in (file.tmp) do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "filestamp=%YYYY% %MM% %DD% %HH% %Min%"
del file.tmp 2>nul
if not defined yyyy goto :EOF

call :DateToMinutes %filestamp% FileMins
set /a MinsOld=%NowMins%-%FileMins%
goto :EOF

:DateToMinutes
setlocal
set yy=%1&set mm=%2&set dd=%3&set hh=%4&set nn=%5
if 1%yy% LSS 200 if 1%yy% LSS 170 (set yy=20%yy%) else (set yy=19%yy%)
set /a dd=100%dd%%%100,mm=100%mm%%%100
set /a z=14-mm,z/=12,y=yy+4800-z,m=mm+12*z-3,j=153*m+2
set /a j=j/5+dd+y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400-2472633
if 1%hh% LSS 20 set hh=0%hh%
if /i {%nn:~2,1%} EQU {p} if "%hh%" NEQ "12" set hh=1%hh%&set/a hh-=88
if /i {%nn:~2,1%} EQU {a} if "%hh%" EQU "12" set hh=00
if /i {%nn:~2,1%} GEQ {a} set nn=%nn:~0,2%
set /a hh=100%hh%%%100,nn=100%nn%%%100,j=j*1440+hh*60+nn
endlocal&set %6=%j%&goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I used your script but I had to change it a bit because it won't work in different languages.
My modified version works on german Windows version and checks a folder every 600 seconds. If there is no change it triggers a notification on ifttt.com causing my phone to beep and so I know my application filling the folder must have crashed.
The watchdog also saves the temp files so I know when was the last checking and what was the differences in each step.

```
echo off
REM Start monitoring C:\Temp\test\tobewatched
REM Goto our "working area"
C:
CD \watchdog
REM Generate initial listing
dir C:\Temp\test\tobewatched\ | FINDSTR /v (se) > old.tmp
:TOP
dir C:\Temp\test\tobewatched\ | FINDSTR /v (se) > new.tmp
fc new.tmp old.tmp
echo %errorlevel%
if errorlevel 1 goto ok
REM Keine Aenderung in 600 Sekunden --> Alarm
curl -X POST https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/notify/with/key/<youriftttkeygoeshere>
:ok

for %%F in (new.tmp) do set file=%%~fF
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic datafile where name^="%file:\=\\%" get lastmodified /format:list') do set datetime=%%I
set datetime=%datetime:~0,14%
copy new.tmp comp%datetime%.txt

del old.tmp 2> nul
ren new.tmp old.tmp
@ping -n 600 localhost> nul
GOTO TOP
```

Comment: keep it international with `dir |findstr /VBC:" "` (removes lines starting with a space, which removes the header and summary lines)